# ag-grid vue wrap text in header and cells

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

For ag-grid vuejs, how do I wrap text in both headers and cell?

This is my example code.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/x98omwov3o

Answer (score 1):

From v28 of AG Grid this is now natively supported for headers too by setting the properties `wrapHeaderText` and `autoHeaderHeight`.

```
const gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    resizable: true,
    wrapHeaderText: true,
    autoHeaderHeight: true,
  },
};
```

You can play with these properties in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FhBacspJwo1YDxDw?open=main.js)

[image: Auto Header Height]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about wrapping text in header, but this is how you could do it for cell.

In your `ColDef`, provide these two properties.

```
  cellClass: "cell-wrap-text",
  autoHeight: true,
```

And CSS will go like this: `.cell-wrap-text { white-space: normal !important; }`

There is also a property available for header, `headerClass: "cell-wrap-text"`, but I was not able to achieve it yet.

Hope it helps a little.